# Openlayers authorization authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication, authorization, token, openlayers

How can i pass jwt token in `Openlayers`. My code is like this. Thanks.

```
    var token = `Bearer-some.token`;

    var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            url: "Geo_JSON_URL",
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
        }),
        style: myStyle,
        zIndex: 10
    })
```

Comment: If your source uses a single geojson it might be simpler to xhr get the geojson before creating the layer source with a features array read from the geojson.  Otherwise, as in @JGH's link you would need to write a custom loader function for the source and set the jwt authorization header in the xhr.